# Oracle 11gR2 installation in Windows server 2012

Tags: oracle11g, windows-server-2012

While installing *Oracle 11gr2* it gives the error

> [INS-13001] Environment does not meet minimum requirements.

I've looked at the prerequisites given at the  Oracle website, but everything seems to be there. There is this log file genereated, but I am not able to tell what it's looking for.

```
sing paramFile: E:\win64_11gR2_client\win64_11gR2_client\client\install\oraparam.ini


Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.    Actual 4294967296    Passed

The commandline for unzip:
E:\win64_11gR2_client\win64_11gR2_client\client\install\unzip -qqqo ..\stage\Components\oracle.jdk\1.5.0.17.04\1\DataFiles/"*.jar" -d "C:\Users\shakyrx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\OraInstall2013-09-24_12-04-54PM" INFO: Loading data from: jar:file:/C:/Users/shakyrx/AppData/Local/Temp/2/OraInstall2013-09-24_12-04-54PM/ext/jlib/installcommons_1.0.0b.jar!/oracle/install/driver/oui/resource/ConfigCommandMappings.xml
INFO: Loading beanstore from jar:file:/C:/Users/shakyrx/AppData/Local/Temp/2/OraInstall2013-09-24_12-04-54PM/ext/jlib/installcommons_1.0.0b.jar!/oracle/install/driver/oui/resource/ConfigCommandMappings.xml
INFO: Restoring class oracle.install.driver.oui.ConfigCmdMappings from jar:file:/C:/Users/shakyrx/AppData/Local/Temp/2/OraInstall2013-09-24_12-04-54PM/ext/jlib/installcommons_1.0.0b.jar!/oracle/install/driver/oui/resource/ConfigCommandMappings.xml
INFO: Verifying target environment...
INFO: Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined...
SEVERE: CVU do not support target environment..
Refer associated stacktrace #oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver:13
INFO: Completed verification of target environment.
WARNING: Verification of target environment returned with errors.
WARNING: [WARNING] [INS-13001] Environment does not meet minimum requirements.
   CAUSE: Minimum requirements were not met for this environment
   ACTION: Either check the logs for more information or check the supported configurations for this product..
Refer associated stacktrace #oracle.install.commons.util.exception.DefaultErrorAdvisor:16
INFO: Advice is WITHDRAW
WARNING: Advised to shutdown the installer due to target environment verification errors.
INFO: Adding ExitStatus PREREQ_FAILURE to the exit status set
INFO: Finding the most appropriate exit status for the current application
INFO: Exit Status is -3
INFO: Shutdown Oracle Client Installer
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

From what I have been able to find, Windows 2012 won't be officially supported until 11.2.0.4 (which is currently only released for Linux/Solaris).

See Oracle Doc "Oracle Database and Client Windows Installation Certification Quick Reference (Doc ID 1231433.1)"

Comment: But I used oracle client in my other environment and it worked fine with windows server 2012 with driver showing up in odbc connector 64 bit and working as expected.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47959/pre_install.htm#NTCLI1255 States that Windows 2012 and 2012 R2 are supported. This is for the client, and i'm assuming the OP is installing the client based on the installation path seen in the log.

Answer (score 1):

the warning can be ignored and you can install it as windows cant provide the required file for verification.. not that it didn't have the requirements but that the response is not in the format needed by oracle software.. hence the error statement says it cant be verified and not it doesn't satisfy the requirement..

you can check it from the below data

```
---# Begin Stacktrace #---------------------------
ID: 
oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver:13
oracle.cluster.verification.PreReqNotSupportedException: 
Reference data is not available for verifying prerequisites on this operating system distribution
    at oracle.cluster.verification.constraints.XmlTaskFactory.getTasks(XmlTaskFactory.java:248)
    at oracle.ops.verification.framework.util.VerificationUtil.isPreReqSupported(VerificationUtil.java:4538)
    at oracle.ops.verification.framework.util.VerificationUtil.isPreReqSupported(VerificationUtil.java:4487)
    at oracle.cluster.verification.ClusterVerification.isPreReqSupported(ClusterVerification.java:6382)
    at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver.verifyEnvironment(OUISetupDriver.java:299)
    at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver.load(OUISetupDriver.java:422)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBSetupDriver.load(DBSetupDriver.java:161)
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.run(Installer.java:216)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.run(DBInstaller.java:129)
    at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:869)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:164)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:265)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:117)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.main(DBInstaller.java:148)

---# End Stacktrace #-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install the 32-bit version of the client it is not supported on WS2012

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47959/pre_install.htm#NTCLI1253

Comment: I mourn, Access Violation in oraociei11.dll reading location 0x00003139 when trying to connect on WS2012.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Oracle 11.2.0.4 on Windows Server 2012. This can be downloaded from My Oracle Support (https://support.oracle.com). See Patch 13390677 in there.

Oracle 11.2.0.1 is available from downloads.oracle.com without a support account, but is not supported on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, i think it is due to CVU (cluster Verification Utility), check the installation temp logs (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\OraInstall2014-04-11_04-40-58PM) and you will see something like this:

```
---# Begin Stacktrace #---------------------------
ID: oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver:13
oracle.cluster.verification.PreReqNotSupportedException: Reference data is not available for verifying prerequisites on this operating system distribution
    at oracle.cluster.verification.constraints.XmlTaskFactory.getTasks(XmlTaskFactory.java:248)
    at oracle.ops.verification.framework.util.VerificationUtil.isPreReqSupported(VerificationUtil.java:4538)
    at oracle.ops.verification.framework.util.VerificationUtil.isPreReqSupported(VerificationUtil.java:4487)
    at oracle.cluster.verification.ClusterVerification.isPreReqSupported(ClusterVerification.java:6382)
    at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver.verifyEnvironment(OUISetupDriver.java:299)
    at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver.load(OUISetupDriver.java:422)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBSetupDriver.load(DBSetupDriver.java:161)
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.run(Installer.java:216)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.run(DBInstaller.java:129)
    at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:869)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:164)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:265)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:117)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.main(DBInstaller.java:148)

---# End Stacktrace #-----------------------------
---# Begin Stacktrace #---------------------------
ID: oracle.install.commons.util.exception.DefaultErrorAdvisor:16
oracle.cluster.verification.PreReqNotSupportedException: Reference data is not available for verifying prerequisites on this operating system distribution
    at oracle.cluster.verification.constraints.XmlTaskFactory.getTasks(XmlTaskFactory.java:248)
    at oracle.ops.verification.framework.util.VerificationUtil.isPreReqSupported(VerificationUtil.java:4538)
    at oracle.ops.verification.framework.util.VerificationUtil.isPreReqSupported(VerificationUtil.java:4487)
    at oracle.cluster.verification.ClusterVerification.isPreReqSupported(ClusterVerification.java:6382)
    at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver.verifyEnvironment(OUISetupDriver.java:299)
    at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver.load(OUISetupDriver.java:422)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBSetupDriver.load(DBSetupDriver.java:161)
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.run(Installer.java:216)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.run(DBInstaller.java:129)
    at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:869)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:164)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:265)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:117)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.main(DBInstaller.java:148)

---# End Stacktrace #-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

my two cents..
I got a similar error.. [INS-13001]

it was a VERY trivial issue: this bogus installer does NOT accept workstation BIOS names with underscore... (God forgive them).
My BIOS name was:

PC_GEC

changing to PCGEC it did install.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the setup.exe file as 'Run as Adminsitrator'

Worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

just right-click on the Setup.exe then locate for Troubleshoot compatibility, then choose recommended by the system.