# Oracle 11g R2 Installation error -13001

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g, windows-8.1

First I need to inform , the same question is posted here :[Oracle 11gR2 installation in Windows server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988156/oracle-11gr2-installation-in-windows-server-2012) . which does not solved my issue. And the links i found on goolge either did not work out or very old.

I am very new to Oracle Database . I am trying to install oracle standard edition . I am getting "Minimum requirements were not met for this environment" error but my system has 8G RAM , windows 8.1 Enterprise Edition , and enough Hard disk space .

When I checked the log file I am seeing "CVU do not support target environment.." as error .

Here is the full log Details :

```
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors. Actual 4294967296    Passed

 The commandline for unzip:
  C:\Users\****\Software\Oracle\Enterprise Edition\win64_11gR2_database_1of2\database\install\unzip -qqqo ..\stage\Components\oracle.jdk\1.5.0.17.04\1\DataFiles/"*.jar" -d "C:\Users\VIGNES~1\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2015-07-08_07-11-47PM" INFO: Loading data from: jar:file:/C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Temp/OraInstall2015-07-08_07-11-47PM/ext/jlib/installcommons_1.0.0b.jar!/oracle/install/driver/oui/resource/ConfigCommandMappings.xml
  INFO: Loading beanstore from jar:file:/C:/Users/*****/AppData/Local/Temp/OraInstall2015-07-08_07-11-47PM/ext/jlib/installcommons_1.0.0b.jar!/oracle/install/driver/oui/resource/ConfigCommandMappings.xml
  INFO: Restoring class oracle.install.driver.oui.ConfigCmdMappings from jar:file:/C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Temp/OraInstall2015-07-08_07-11-47PM/ext/jlib/installcommons_1.0.0b.jar!/oracle/install/driver/oui/resource/ConfigCommandMappings.xml
  INFO: Verifying target environment...
  INFO: Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined...
  SEVERE: CVU do not support target environment..
  Refer associated stacktrace #oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver:13
  INFO: Completed verification of target environment.
  WARNING: Verification of target environment returned with errors.
  WARNING: [WARNING] [INS-13001] Environment does not meet minimum requirements.
  CAUSE: Minimum requirements were not met for this environment
  ACTION: Either check the logs for more information or check the supported configurations for this product..
  Refer associated stacktrace #oracle.install.commons.util.exception.DefaultErrorAdvisor:16
  INFO: Advice is WITHDRAW
  WARNING: Advised to shutdown the installer due to target environment verification errors.
  INFO: Adding ExitStatus PREREQ_FAILURE to the exit status set
```

Error log :

```
   ---# Begin Stacktrace #---------------------------
   ID: oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver:13
   oracle.cluster.verification.PreReqNotSupportedException: Reference data is not available for verifying prerequisites on this operating system distribution
at oracle.cluster.verification.constraints.XmlTaskFactory.getTasks(XmlTaskFactory.java:248)
at oracle.ops.verification.framework.util.VerificationUtil.isPreReqSupported(VerificationUtil.java:4538)
at oracle.ops.verification.framework.util.VerificationUtil.isPreReqSupported(VerificationUtil.java:4487)
at oracle.cluster.verification.ClusterVerification.isPreReqSupported(ClusterVerification.java:6382)
at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver.verifyEnvironment(OUISetupDriver.java:299)
at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver.load(OUISetupDriver.java:422)
at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBSetupDriver.load(DBSetupDriver.java:161)
at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.run(Installer.java:216)
at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.run(DBInstaller.java:129)
at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:869)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:164)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:265)
at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:117)
at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.main(DBInstaller.java:148)

 ---# End Stacktrace #-----------------------------
 ---# Begin Stacktrace #---------------------------
  ID: oracle.install.commons.util.exception.DefaultErrorAdvisor:16
  oracle.cluster.verification.PreReqNotSupportedException: Reference data is not available for verifying prerequisites on this operating system distribution
at oracle.cluster.verification.constraints.XmlTaskFactory.getTasks(XmlTaskFactory.java:248)
at oracle.ops.verification.framework.util.VerificationUtil.isPreReqSupported(VerificationUtil.java:4538)
at oracle.ops.verification.framework.util.VerificationUtil.isPreReqSupported(VerificationUtil.java:4487)
at oracle.cluster.verification.ClusterVerification.isPreReqSupported(ClusterVerification.java:6382)
at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver.verifyEnvironment(OUISetupDriver.java:299)
at oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver.load(OUISetupDriver.java:422)
at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBSetupDriver.load(DBSetupDriver.java:161)
at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.run(Installer.java:216)
at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.run(DBInstaller.java:129)
at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:869)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:164)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:265)
at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:117)
at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.main(DBInstaller.java:148)

 ---# End Stacktrace #-----------------------------
```

**NOTE :** I already installed Oracle 11g Express Edition which works great .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CVU is the Cluster Verification Utility. Unless you're installing a RAC (ie, cluster of Oracle nodes) infrastructure, it's safe to ignore this error and continue with the installation.

This error is happening because the installer can't find the file to verify the minimum requirements for a Oracle cluster installation.